# Refresh SWC in FlexBuilder after publishing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flexbuilder

I am using a SWC that was published from Flash CS3 in an Actionscript project in FlexBuider. The problem is that every time I make a change and re-publish the SWC the changes I made are not immediately recognized back in FlexBuilder.

In order to have newly published SWC recognized I have to remove the reference to the SWC from the library path and then add it back again. This is tedious.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is to go into the project's properties and click on the ActionScript Build Path. In the Library Path tab you should see your SWC files and folders. Go ahead and delete then add the SWC back. This will make Flex rebuild its cache.

There is also an archived support document form Adobe on how to make sure this works:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/192/tn_19283.html

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the libs folder and press refresh.
Easy as pie.

Comment: Hmm - I don't seem to have a libs folder.

Comment: I think that is only for flex projects?